# Unable to export particular data from a .json file from a website

Tags: javascript, python, json, pandas

I'm using the following to parse data from a website:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

resp = requests.get("https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=1000000&page=1").json()
df = pd.DataFrame(resp['posts'], columns=['episodeNumber','slug','image','excerpt','audioSource'])    
df.to_csv("output9.csv", encoding='utf-8', index='false')

data = pd.read_csv("output9.csv")
```

As you can see, I've had to pull the entire 'excerpt' column which pulls all three instead of just one. How would I go about just pulling say the 'short' one? What is the heading called instead of 'column'? Also, the 'title' doesn't seem to be under any sort of header - how would I pull this too?

A quick visual of the .json is here if it helps:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v9l81ber6i4nbgw/11111111.jpg?dl=0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken the `excerpt` series, called the `apply` function and took the 'short' series which was created from `apply`. You might have to handle the extra double quotes, consider the following code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

resp = requests.get("https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=1000000&page=1").json()
df = pd.DataFrame(resp['posts'], columns=['episodeNumber','slug','image','excerpt','audioSource'])    
df['excerpt'] = df['excerpt'].apply(pd.Series)['short']#.replace({'"': '\'','""': '\'','"""': '\'' }, regex=True)
df.to_csv("output9.csv", encoding='utf-8', index='false')
data = pd.read_csv("output9.csv")
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much! Would you know how to insert the 'title' section? It's not under the same column format as the episode description or images are? Doesn't show up in the same way when I use a .json viewer.

Comment: I don't understand, if you want the title you could add `title` in `columns` like so `df = pd.DataFrame(resp['posts'], columns=['title','episodeNumber','slug','image','excerpt','audioSource'])` or if you're talking about `prev` then you could use the same code that I have used in the answer for `excerpt`

Answer (score 2):

The workaround which I can think of is to normalizes the resp['posts'] json and dont mention the columns. Below is the code to generate the above dataframe:

```
    import requests
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

    resp = requests.get("https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=1000000&page=1").json()
    # print(resp['posts'][0])
    df = pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(resp['posts']))
    df.to_csv("output2_9.csv", encoding='utf-8', index='false')
```

Now once you have this dataframe u can filter which ever column you want it has all the field of json and column names as :
**audioSource   content date    episodeNumber   excerpt.full    excerpt.long    excerpt.short   id  image.full  image.large image.medium    image.thumb musicCredits    next    next.slug   next.title  permalink   prev    prev.slug   prev.title  slug    title**

The title header is also present in this dataframe